# How to calculate the total price from one data grid view and update it then show it in another dataGridViwe C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, window

what am doing is a pizza menu, and I have 3 dataGridView, 1st to show the menu, 2nd to show the ingredients from the selected pizza, and 3rd to show a list of ingredients (the user can add remove ingredient). The thing is I need to calculate the price of the ingredient from the 2nd DGV by updating it automatically and then show the final price in 1st DGV

```
pizzaGrid.DataSource = SelectedList;
DataGridViewCell pizzacell = MenuGrid.CurrentCell;
DataGridViewCell ingrecell = IngredientCell.Currentcell;
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < ingredientList.Count; i++)
{
    Ingredient ingre = ingredientList[i];
    if(ingredientList.Contain(i))
    {
        total++;
        SelectedList.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code so far? If so add it to your question, if not: StackOverflow is ment for specific implementation questions, not for us to do the coding for you. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @FreekW, I have tried doing for loop but it didnt work

Comment: Then add that code, also add the code that adds the items (pizza's and ingredients in this case), because your description of the rather vague.

Comment: I had attached a screenshot of the code that I had tried @FreekW

Answer (score 0):

if i understands your question correct you want to calculate the total price of  all the values in a column from a datagrid you can try some thing like this

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
label1.text = sum.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build a method that looks something like this:

```
private double calculatePrice()
{
    double sum = 0; //Double, because we are dealing with money, which is a decimal

    for(int i = 0; i < IngredientGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToDouble(IngredientGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value); //This takes the value of your selected cell within your ingredients datagrid (they need to be only numbers, no letters since we're converting to a double)
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And you then call this method on for instance an index changed or whenever like this:

```
label1.Text = calculatePrice().ToString();
```

Comment: I Have done something similar, but I haven't use the converting since I typed the code in the class in a method and it works. But the thing is it does not update automatically, I need to click on the cell of the calculated price and then it will be updated

Comment: If you want to `update` something, you are going to want to update is after you've done something worth updating right? Whenever you do that something, you call this method. (You can update on `FormLoad` or any interaction with the form for that matter). If you're looking to update annualy, create a `Timer`. Set the `interval` to the desired ammount and you're done.